# Missing exception stack trace informations when using Async Targeting Pack in Silverlight 5.0

Tags: .net, silverlight-5.0, stack-trace, async-await

I'm using Async Targeting Pack in Silverlight 5.0 application. When unhandled exception occurs in some async method (assuming from async "state machine"), stack trace of the exception than contains only:

in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b__0(Object state)

end not any other code locations.

Comment: How can I get "full" stack trace or find out actual location, where exception occured? Is this some bug of targeting pack or it is simply not supported?

Comment: This means that the exception happened after first await call, but before the end. Since async functions are by default state machines, the stack trace is lost.

Comment: @ToniPetrina , couldn't grasp... why after "first"? If exception happens after N-th await call but before the end. what's the difference?

Comment: The difference is huge. When you return in the function after awaiting, the stack trace must be different. After all, you didn't come to that point from function call, you came as a continuation for the awaited task.